# Pass a table variable to stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Sale]
(
    [SaleId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    [SaleDate] [datetime] NOT NULL DEFAULT GETDATE(),
    [UserPhone] char(10) NOT NULL,
    [NumberSale] [int] NOT NULL,
)
```

Then I have this table variable

```
DECLARE @sale1 TABLE  
               (
                   Phone char(10), 
                   GoodId int, 
                   GoodCount int
               )

INSERT INTO @sale1 
VALUES ('0671112221', 1, 2),
       ('0671112221', 4, 1),
       ('0671112221', 13, 2);
```

I am creating a stored procedure to  input data into the table using table variable. But table is underlined.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spSalesAndSalesPosInsert
    @data table -- here is  a mistake 
AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
        BEGIN TRANSACTION;
            
        INSERT INTO Sale (UserPhone, NumberSale)
            SELECT Phone, GoodCount 
            FROM @data
        
        COMMIT TRANSACTION;
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;       
    END CATCH;
END;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The `table` keyword is reserved for other scenarios than passing a parameter.

Have look a [this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-table-valued-parameters-database-engine#Example) from the documentation that passes a *table-valued parameter* to a stored procedure by creating a [user-defined type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-type-transact-sql).

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare a user-defined type for the table.

```
CREATE TYPE myTableType AS TABLE
(
    Phone char(10), GoodId int, GoodCount int
)
```

Then you can use it:

```
declare @sale1 myTableType
insert into @sale1 
values
('0671112221', 1, 2),
('0671112221', 4, 1),
('0671112221', 13, 2);

create proc spSalesAndSalesPosInsert
@data myTableType
as
begin
    --Etc....
```

Comment: And the parameter must be `@data myTableType READONLY` since only read-only table-value type parameters are supported in SQL Server at this time